# Extract data from paginated database entries and pass to a form

Tags: php, forms, pagination

Stack Overflow won't allow me to post more than 2 hyperlinks and I need three, so to see my inquiry properly, please click on the link below:
http://bretleduc.com/inquiry.htm

This page I made:
[Paginated Data][1]

Shows questions/comments that people have entered in the following page:
[Contact Artist][2]

The theory is, once someone posts a comment or question, the artist (Jackson David, whom I'm making this page for) can see the comment and respond to it in the [Respond to a Question or Comment][3] page.  But right now, the artist has to copy and paste the Name and Email Address from the [Paginated Data][1] section to the [Respond to a Question or Comment][3] form.

What I'm trying to do is modify the [Paginated Data][1] page to include the ability to select an entry and have the Name and Email Address populate the Name and Email Address fields in another form.  This way, the artist can answer the customer's queries easier by just clicking on the paginated entry (maybe using a radio button for example) and having the customer's Name and Email Address automatically populate into the following form:
[Respond to a Question or Comment][3]

Here is the code for the [Paginated Data][1] page which I got from a script site:

```
<?php
// Adam's Custom PHP MySQL Pagination Tutorial and Script
// You have to put your mysql connection data and alter the SQL queries(both queries)
// This script is in tutorial form and is accompanied by the following video:
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8xYGnEOXYc
require("hidden.php");
//////////////  QUERY THE MEMBER DATA INITIALLY LIKE YOU NORMALLY WOULD
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT Comment_ID, Name, email, Comment FROM Comments ORDER BY Comment_ID DESC");
//////////////////////////////////// Adam's Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Get total of Num rows from the database query
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { // Get pn from URL vars if it is present
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(new)
    //$pn = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(deprecated)
} else { // If the pn URL variable is not present force it to be value of page number 1
    $pn = 1;
}
//This is where we set how many database items to show on each page
$itemsPerPage = 2;
// Get the value of the last page in the pagination result set
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
// Be sure URL variable $pn(page number) is no lower than page 1 and no higher than $lastpage
if ($pn < 1) { // If it is less than 1
    $pn = 1; // force if to be 1
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { // if it is greater than $lastpage
    $pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value
}
// This creates the numbers to click in between the next and back buttons
// This section is explained well in the video that accompanies this script
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
// This line sets the "LIMIT" range... the 2 values we place to choose a range of rows from database in our query
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;
// Now we are going to run the same query as above but this time add $limit onto the end of the SQL syntax
// $sql2 is what we will use to fuel our while loop statement below
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT Comment_ID, Name, email, Comment FROM Comments ORDER BY Comment_ID DESC $limit");
//////////////////////////////// END Adam's Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////// Adam's Pagination Display Setup /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable
// This code runs only if the last page variable is ot equal to 1, if it is only 1 page we require no paginated links to display
if ($lastPage != "1"){
    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
    // If we are not on page 1 we can place the Back button
    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    }
    // Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    // If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button
    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////// END Adam's Pagination Display Setup ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Build the Output Section Here
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

    $Comment_ID = $row["Comment_ID"];
    $Name = $row["Name"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $Comment = $row["Comment"];

    $outputList .= '<h1>' . $Name . '</h1><h2>' . $email . '<br />' . $Comment . '</h2><hr />';

} // close while loop
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adam's Pagination</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.pagNumActive {
    color: #000;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
     <h2>Total Items: <?php echo $nr; ?></h2>
   </div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
      <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;"><?php print "$outputList"; ?></div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I need to put some sort of form in the following line from the code:

```
$outputList .= '<h1>' . $Name . '</h1><h2>' . $email . '<br />' . $Comment . '</h2><hr />';
```

Further, it would be a bonus if we could make the selection of the entry automatically post the Name and Email Address to the
[Respond to a Question or Comment][3]
form without having to click a submit button.

If it would be easier to combine the code of [Paginated Data][1] and the code of [Respond to a Question or Comment][3] into one page, I can do that too.

Thanks all!

Comment: Adam is the wrong guy to be learning from!

Comment: @marabutt OK, thanks.  So then what/who would you recommend?

Comment: **UPDATE** I added a form to the $outputList variable in [link](http://webpages.sou.edu/~allredj/page.php).  Here is the code: `    $outputList .= '<form action="sendemail.php" method="post" name="pageForm" id="pageForm">' . '<h1>' . $Name . '</h1><br /><h2>' . '<input type="radio" id="pageEmail" name="pageEmail" value=' . $email . ' onclick="document.getElementById(\'submit\').click();"/>' . $email . '<br />' . $Comment . '<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Choose" style="visibility:hidden"/></h2></form><hr />';` **BUT** the sendemail.php does not populate the email field on submit.

Comment: **UPDATE**: I changed the id and name to pageRow and changed the value to $row hoping that the row info would get passed.  I added a database query to the sendemail.php page: `$sql5 = mysql_query("SELECT Name, email, Comment FROM Comments WHERE row=$pageRow");` **BUT** the info is still not populated :(

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the page to work through blood sweat and tears. I removed some isset coding that was cluttering the input fields. I also changed the process from _POST to _GET.
Thanks for all your help!